# NextJS adding item to element and rendering in tailwind select keeps throwing errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

Im having a bit of an issue displaying dynamic values into a select box in NextJS

I am getting values from an API endpoint, making sure that data is returned and then displaying it in a select box as below, BUT i want to add an element to the top of the 'teams' array and then make sure on page load that the new element is displayed first.

I have tried adding the following bit of code below and above the api call, but it keeps returning errors

```
const newData = {id: 1, team_name: 'Personal'}
teams.push(newData)
setSelected(newData[0])
```

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I have also tried adding a `useEffect` hook and then setting the selected, but this also returns errors.

Nothing I do seems to let me do this.

Any help would be amazing

```
const Create () => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState()

    const { data: teams, error, mutate } = useSWR('/teams', () => 
        axios.get('/teams')
            .then(response => response.data.data)
        )

    if (!teams) {
        return (<LoadPageSpinner />)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Listbox value={selected} onChange={setSelected}>
                {({ open }) => (
                    <>
                        <Listbox.Label className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Assigned to</Listbox.Label>
                        <div className="relative mt-2">
                            <Listbox.Button className="relative w-full cursor-default rounded-md bg-white py-1.5 pl-3 pr-10 text-left text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6">
                                <span className="block truncate">{selected}</span>
                                <span className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2">
                                    <ChevronUpDownIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
                                </span>
                            </Listbox.Button>

                            <Transition
                                show={open}
                                as={Fragment}
                                leave="transition ease-in duration-100"
                                leaveFrom="opacity-100"
                                leaveTo="opacity-0"
                            >
                                <Listbox.Options className="absolute z-10 mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
                                    {teams.map((team) => (
                                        <Listbox.Option
                                            key={team.id}
                                            className={({ active }) =>
                                                classNames(
                                                    active ? 'bg-indigo-600 text-white' : 'text-gray-900',
                                                    'relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-3 pr-9'
                                                )
                                            }
                                            value={team.team_name}
                                        >
                                            {({ selected, active }) => (
                                                <>
                                                    <span className={classNames(selected ? 'font-semibold' : 'font-normal', 'block truncate')}>
                                                        {team.team_name}
                                                    </span>

                                                    {selected ? (
                                                        <span
                                                            className={classNames(
                                                                active ? 'text-white' : 'text-indigo-600',
                                                                'absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4'
                                                            )}
                                                        >
                                                            <CheckIcon className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                                                        </span>
                                                    ) : null}
                                                </>
                                            )}
                                        </Listbox.Option>
                                    ))}
                                </Listbox.Options>
                            </Transition>
                        </div>
                    </>
                )}
            </Listbox>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
const personal = { id: 1, team_name: 'Personal' }
const {
  data: teams,
  error,
  mutate
} = useSWR('/teams', () =>
  axios.get('/teams').then((response) => [personal, ...response.data.data])
)
```

I'm placing the extra item in a new array containing it and everything in the response.

Comment: Owww that works, except is there a way to then `setSelected` state to the first `teams` item when it loads?

Comment: You have not shown the type of what `setSelected` expects. Is it the entire object or just the id of an object? Anyway, you can simply place whatever it expects into `useState(initialValueHere)`.